# How to rename netcdf variable with python

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf4

I have a netcdf file and need to rename the keys of variables.
Here what I tried:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8
import netCDF4 as nc
fn='L1AHITBR'
ds = nc.Dataset(fn)
print(ds.variables.keys())
ds.renameVariable('himawari_9_ahi_channel_10_brightness_temperature','himawari_8_ahi_channel_10_brightness_temperature')
```

When running this code I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
ds.renameVariable('himawari_9_ahi_channel_10_brightness_temperature','himawari_8_ahi_channel_10_brightness_temperatue')
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2989, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.renameVariable
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2028, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
RuntimeError: NetCDF: Write to read only
```

My version on netcdf4 for python is 1.6.2

Thanks for insights

Best

Comment: You have to specify the mode -- either you open the dataset for reading, for writing or for changing. At the moment, the default value in nc.Dataset is mode='r' i.e. reading.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by msi_gerva, the solution was to open in the correct mode.

```
ds = nc.Dataset(fn,mode='a')
```